# Is it possible to list files using ls with du directory size?

Tags: ls, disk-usage

I'd like to list all the conterns of a directory (including subdirs) and their real size (including dir sizes). I can list them with `ls`, and I can see the size of each with `du -sh`. But is there a way to list all with `du`'s size output?

Comment: `du` reports *disk usage*, not *size*

Comment: Is `du -bhlsc -- *` what you're after assuming GNU du? (or without `-b` if you want the disk usage instead of size, beware of the implication of `-l`). Replace `*` with `*(D)`, assuming zsh if you also want hidden files to be listed.

Comment: Thank you. Please note that what i'd like is to list only the contents of the current directory ("max depth 1"), but for all sub-directories of the current directory indicate as "size" not the default 4k-Block of the dir entry, but the cumulative size of the contained files as noted by AdminBee below

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to list the contents of a directory recursively (also the subdirectories up to the leaf nodes), with the actual size (I'm going to understand it as you want it in a human readable format).

You can do this simply with `ls`, where `R` refers to recursion, `l` indicates that you want it in list format and `h` in human format:

```
ls -Rlh
```

Comment: I'm not sure about that. If I understood the OP correctly, the aim is to list only the contents of the current directory ("max depth 1"), but for all sub-directories of the current directory indicate as "size" not the default 4k-Block of the dir entry, but the cumulative size of the contained files.

Comment: AdminBee you're right, that's what I'm trying to do